# Test Slack team_join event with Postman

Tags: postman, slack-api

I've followed [this Slack tutorial](https://github.com/slackapi/Slack-Ruby-Onboarding-Tutorial) to create an onboarding bot that gives people a few tips on how to interaction with other members. The tutorial recommends using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test onboard experience, but it's not clear on how. I'm getting stuck on this: **where do I put the a authorization token?**

*Prereqs:*

- [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is running on port 9292
- `rackup` was run to start the server
- I followed all steps to configure the Slack app as shown in the tutorial
- I clicked the Slack button to authorize the application

*What I'm doing:*

Using Postman macOS client to send this default JSON event for `team_join` to the [`/events` endpoint](https://github.com/slackapi/Slack-Ruby-Onboarding-Tutorial/blob/master/bot.rb#L44):

```
{
    "type": "team_join",
    "user": {
    "id": "U023BECGF",
    "name": "bobby",
    "deleted": false,
    "color": "9f69e7",
    "profile": {
        "first_name": "Bobby",
        "last_name": "Tables",
        "real_name": "Bobby Tables",
        "email": "bobby@slack.com"
    },
    "is_admin": true,
    "is_owner": true,
    "is_primary_owner": true,
    "is_restricted": false,
    "is_ultra_restricted": false,
    "has_2fa": false,
    "two_factor_type": "sms"
    }
}
```

I've tried including `token` as a parameter, header key/value and within the JSON object. None of these approaches seems to do it and it results in an authorization error. I get `Invalid Slack verification token received:` or a parsing issue.

How does one test something like a new user joining using this setup?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Sinatra, but in [line 49](https://github.com/slackapi/Slack-Ruby-Onboarding-Tutorial/blob/master/bot.rb#L49), is `SLACK_CONFIG[:slack_verification_token]` actually set? if you print both this and the token value, are they the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token is available within the Event envelope, so you'll need to go up one level in the JSON:

```
{
"token": "{{verification_token}}",
"team_id": "{{team_id}}",
"api_app_id": "{{app_id}}",
"event": {
    "type": "team_join",
    "user": {
        "id": "{{user_id}}",
        "team_id": "{{team_id}}",
        "name": "{{user_name}}",
        "deleted": false,
        "status": null,
        "real_name": "{{user_real_name}}",
        "profile": {
            "first_name": "{{user_first_name}}",
            "last_name": "{{user_last_name}}",
            "real_name": "{{user_real_name}}",
            "real_name_normalized": "{{user_real_name}}"
        },
        "is_bot": false
    }
},
"type": "event_callback",
"authed_users": ["{{authed_user}}"]
```

}

Comment: Thanks @roach, though it's not doing the trick just yet. I've got everything setup based on the tutorial, authed and all, but keep getting: "NoMethodError at /events undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass file: bot.rb location: user_join line: 100"